# How to move cursor with a sphere and move it to tangent of the base's upper face?

Tags: snapping, 3d-cursor

I am trying to move a sphere onto a face of the base rectangle. I moved 3D-cursor to tip vertex of the sphere and open snap-magnet and active object with align properties but I could not move sphere onto the base rectangle, when I try to move sphere, 3D-cursor not moves with sphere. How can I move cursor with sphere? My aim is to move sphere to tangent of the base's upper face.

Comment: Snapping has nothing to do with the 3D cursor! If you've selected 'Face' in the snapping dropdown, click on the snapping icon to activate it. Select the sphere, hover the mouse over the face of the base rectangle and hit 'G' (then 'Z' if you want the sphere to go straight down). Incidentally, I assume you mean Blender 2.83. 2.85 doesn't exist.

Comment: I see @Crantisz has clarified and answered this now. The 'Closest' option is selected by default both in Blender 2.83 and 3.0 here which is why it didn't occur to me to mention it.

Comment: That's ok. No problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up snapping like this:

[image]

Snap with "Closest" makes object snaps by its boundaries instead of center